# Error :"The method or operation is not implemented." in Settings.settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I get this error message in VS2013: "The method or operation is not implemented." opening Settings.settings from solution explorer, same issue with properties/settings..
Any Hints?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved, the app.config contained mismatching values from the settings.setting, a restart of VS solved, asking what to do with mismatches.

Comment: Also a simple restart fixed it for me on VS2015

Comment: Also belongs to VS2017

Comment: For VS2019, I managed to get it open without a restart. All i had to do was open the app.config that had the settings in it, and after that the settings editor would open naturally.

Comment: Project in VS2022 doesnt have an app.config

Answer (score 1):

For VS2019, I could also fix it like described by MercifulGiraffe
But I also found another way, by running VS as administrator...
I also had issues when I wanted to switch the framework version, it failed with the error message "Value does not fall within the expected range"... running it as administrator solved everything